# iOS - Serialize JSON with arabic NSString

Tags: iphone, json, utf-8

I'm in quite a pickle, I'm acquiring user input in Arabic which is stored in a `NSString`.
The string is displayed properly both in the app and the debug window.

Here's my problem: the string is added to a `NSMutableDictionary` then serialized to **JSON**

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                     error:&error];
```

The data is then POSTed to the server, but the once Arabic content is represented as `????`

This is obviously an encoding issue. I can't find the proper method to encode my `NSString` with **UTF-8** and still add it to the Dictionary. 
AddingPercentEncoding will encode it as URL UTF-8 encoding which is not what I'm after.
The only reasonable encoding I find is `[NSString UTF8String]` which turns the string to `const char *` that is not an `NSObject`.

What I'm really after is: **مرحبا** UTF-8 ---> **ÙØ±Ø­Ø¨Ø§**

The decoding works perfectly,  if the iOS app receives JSON with such representation, the resulting `NSDictionary` will hold a key that returns the proper value in Arabic.

Thank you for your help! :D

Comment: try to post directly to the web server using a browser in your PC. The problem might be from the server

Comment: I POST to the server using QT app from windows, I create a QByteArray = myQString.toUTF8(); then add it to a QMap , and serialize it, works perfectly when decoded on another Qt client , or even from iOS and Android.